# Linking sections in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $featured_query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $slide_more_link = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_et_slide_more_link', true );
    $more_link = '' != $slide_more_link ? $slide_more_link : get_permalink();
    $class = 'et-first';
    $truncate_length = 610;

    $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_image_width', 578 );
    $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_image_height', 420 );
    $title = get_the_title();

    if ( 2 === $i ) {
        $class = 'et-second';
        $truncate_length = 250;
        $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_image_medium_width', 578 );
        $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_image_medium_height', 208 );
    } else if ( 1 !== $i ) {
        $class = 3 === $i ? 'et-third' : 'et-fourth';
        $truncate_length = 75;
        $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_image_small_width', 287 );
        $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_image_small_height', 208 );
    }

    if ( is_category() ) {
        $truncate_length = 390;
        $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_category_image_width', 578 );
        $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_slider_category_image_height', 280 );
    }

    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, '', $title, $title, false, 'Featured' );
    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
?>
```

I want to link each class, so $class= 'et-first'; etc just looking to see how to go about doing this, as I'm a php noob.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Is this a copy paste code?

Comment: Yes it is pasted from my wordpress site